# Modular Arithmetic with Multiple Exponents

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I understand how to do modular arithmetic on numbers with large exponents (like $8^{202}$). However, I am having trouble understanding how to calculate something like:

$ 3^{3^{3^{3^3}}}$ mod 5

(that's 5 3's there). Can anyone help me understand how to get this started?

Comment: $3^{3^{\ldots}}\equiv 3^{3^{\ldots}\pmod{4}}\equiv 3^{(-1)^{\ldots}}\equiv 3^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod{5}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, it suffices to look at the exponent modulo 4, so the problem reduces to finding $3^{3^{3^3}}$ modulo 4. But $3^{3^{3^3}} \equiv (-1)^{(-1)^{3^3}} \equiv (-1)^{-1} \equiv -1 \pmod 4$.

Thus $3^{3^{3^{3^3}}} \equiv 3^{-1} \equiv 2 \pmod 5$.

---

Edit: Fermat's Little Theorem tells us that for any prime $p$, we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for all $a \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$. So, in particular, $a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ provided $a \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$, which is why we can reduce the exponent modulo 4.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information? I thought Fermat's Little Theorem was used for something completely different.

Comment: @WinterStar My comment to your question shows exactly how it should be used for this problem. It works very well for reducing the exponent of a number if the number is coprime to the prime modulus (it is coprime to the prime modulus iff it is not divisible by $p$).

Comment: ... look at the exponent mod $4$, not mod $5.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for catching that; I fixed it.

Comment: @WinterStar I added a brief explanation on FLT.

Comment: Can you please show how $ 3^{-1} \equiv 2 \pmod 5$

Comment: @ErikMartinesSanches Since $3\cdot2 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, it follows that the inverse of $3$ is $2$. Compare this to normal arithmetic, where $3\cdot\frac13 = 1$, and in that case $3^{-1} = \frac13$.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with tetration, numbers really go out of hand...
I've never seen modular arithmetic operated on tetrated numbers..

$$3\uparrow\uparrow1 = 3^1$$ mod 5 on this yields 3
$$3\uparrow\uparrow2 = 3^3$$ mod 5 on this yields a 2
$$3\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3^{(3^3)} = 3^{27}$$ mod 5 on this (Online calc) yields a two as well.
Problem is, calculators (Atleast the ones available online), aren't able to calculate after this.

You're asking  $$(3\uparrow\uparrow5) mod (5) = 3^{3^{3^{3^3}}} mod (5) $$
This may be of interest...https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0535.03018&format=complete http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122183901141

You can also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function;  http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=45 for some ideas.

I'm not much into Mod arithmetic; but the two articles I've provided may be of some help, as they directly deal with your doubts...

PS: Good question! Definite thumbs up.