# Modular equation with exponents on the exponents

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to solve this modular equation:

$ 7x + 5 \equiv 2^{11^{2017}} \pmod {31}$

As far as I know, dividing the exponent by 31 and substituting it with the remainder is not allowed.

I've looked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161176/modular-arithmetic-with-multiple-exponents) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) but I don't see how to apply that to my equation. 
I'm sorry for this short question but I don't really know how to approach this equation.

Comment: Apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know, dividing the exponent by 31 and substituting it with the remainder is not allowed.

Correct.  $a^k \not \equiv a^{(k\mod n)} \mod n$ is certainly not allowed.

(Although modulo distributes over addition and multiplication; $(a + \text{multiple of }n)\circ(b + \text{multiple of }n)= a\circ b + \text{multiple of }n$ when $\circ$ is either $+$ or $\times$--- it clearly does not distribute over exponents; $a^{k+ \text{multiple of }n} = a^k\times a^{\text{multiple of }n} \ne a^k + \text{multiple of }n$-- it simply does not.)

However you are allowed the two following.

if $a \equiv b \pmod n$ then $a^k \equiv b^k \pmod n$--

and if $a^m\equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $a^{(k\pmod m)} \equiv a^k \mod n$.

This is because $a^{k + m*h} = a^k*(a^m)^h \equiv a^k*(1)^h \equiv a^k \mod n$.

.....

Thus if we know $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$

Then $2^{11^{2017} } \equiv 2^{(11 \pmod m)^{2017}} \pmod {31}$.

So if we know $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$.  And we know $11 \equiv a \mod m$.  And we know $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod m$.  And we know $2017 \equiv b \pmod k$ the we know:

$2^{11^{2017}}\equiv 2^{(11^{2017}\pmod m)} \equiv$

$2^{(11\pmod m)^{2017}}\equiv 2^{a^{2017}} \equiv 2^{a^{2017 \mod k}}$

$2^{a^b} \pmod {31}$.

.....

Which is not as abstract as it looks.

Why know by Fermat's Little Theorem that $2^{30} \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ and by experimenting with smaller factors of $30$ we find that $2^5 = 32 \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$.

So $2^{11^{2017}}\equiv 2^{(11^{2017} \mod 5)}\equiv 1 \pmod {31}$.

Now clearly $11^{2017} \equiv 1^{2017} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ so

$2^{11^{2017}}\equiv 2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod {31}$.

....

To put it another way.

$2^{11^{2017}} = 2^{(1 + 10)^{2017}} = 2^{1 + \text{some multiple of } 10}=$

$2*2^{\text{some multiple of } 10} = 2*((2^5)^2)^{\text{some integer}}=$

$2*(32)^{2*\text{some integer}} \equiv 2*1^{2*\text{some integer}}\pmod {32} \equiv 2\pmod {31}$.

=====

Oh, to actually solve the original question:

$7x + 5 \equiv 2^{11^{2017}} \pmod {31}$

$7x + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod {31}$

$7x \equiv -3 \pmod {31}$

Well, we could get lucky and notice $7x \equiv -3 \equiv 28\pmod {31}$ so $x \equiv 4 \pmod {31}$ will be *one* set of solutions.  But is it the only one?  And could we have solved it without getting lucky?

Well, we know if $\gcd (n,k) =1$ then we know that there exist $x, m$ so that $kx + mn = 1$.... or in other words thatn $kx \equiv 1 \mod n$ has a solution.

And if $n$ is prime we know that the solutions to $kx\equiv 1\mod n$ is unique up to modulo $31$ equivalence.

So $7m\equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ has a unique solution.  By brute force/luck we can find that $7*9 = 63 \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$.

So $9$ is the *multiplicative inverse* of $7$ in tems of modulo $31$ equivalence.

So $7x + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod (31)$

$7x  \equiv -3\pmod (31)$

$9*7x \equiv -3*9 \pmod(31)$

$63x \equiv -27 \pmod (31)$

$x \equiv 4 \pmod(31)$.

Answer (score 0):

$2$ has order $5\bmod 31$, so
$$2^{11^{2017}}\equiv2^{11^{2017}\bmod 5}\pmod{31}.$$
Now $11\equiv 1\mod 5$, so $11^{2017}\equiv 1\mod 5$ and eventually $2^{11^{2017}}\equiv2^1=2\mod{31}$, so the congruence equation becomes
$$7x+5\equiv 2\iff7x\equiv -3\iff x\equiv 9(-3)=-27\equiv \color{red}{4}\mod31$$
since $7^{-1}\equiv 9\mod 31$.

Comment: What does it mean that 2 has order 5 mod 31?

Comment: We're in the (multiplicative) group of units mod. $31$. It is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $2^k\equiv 1\mod 31$.

Answer (score 0):

$\!\bmod 31\!:\ 2^{\large\color{#c00} 5}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\large 11^{\Large n}}\!\! \equiv 2^{\large 11^{\Large n}\bmod\color{#c00}5}\!\equiv 2\ $ by $\ 11^{\large n}\equiv 1^{\large n}\equiv 1\pmod{\!\color{#c00}5},\, $ by Lemma below.

Thus  $\,7 x + 5\equiv 2\iff x\equiv \dfrac{-3}{7}\equiv \dfrac{-3\cdot 4}{\,\ \ 7\cdot 4}\equiv \dfrac{-12}{-3}\equiv 4\ $ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242).

---

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large n}\equiv 1}\,\ $ then $\ a^{\large K}\equiv a^{\large k}\ $ if $\,K\equiv k\pmod n $

**Proof** $\ $ Wlog $\,K\ge k\,$ so $\, K = k + jn\ $ for $\ j\ge 0.\ $ Therefore

$$ a^{\large K}\equiv a^{\large k+jn}\equiv a^{\large k} (\color{#c00}{a^{\large n}})^{\large j}\equiv  a^{\large k}\, \color{#c00}{1}^{\large j}\equiv a^k $$

using basic congruence rules such as the [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Answer (score -1):

To solve such question, I would simplify the right hand side first. Notice that ${(2^{11})}^{2017} \equiv 2^{2017} \pmod{31}$. Further more, $2017 = 67 \times 30 + 7$. Therefore, By Fermat's theorem, $2^{2017} \equiv {(2^{30})}^{67} \times 2^7 \equiv 1 \times 2^7 \equiv 128 \equiv 4 \pmod{31}$.

The equation finally becomes

$$7x+5 \equiv 4 \pmod{31} \to 7x \equiv -1 \pmod{31}$$

Notice that I divided by $30$ instead of $31$ when using Fermat little theorem.

Comment: But you are computing the innermost power, instead of starting with the outermost (11^2017). Isn't that invalid?

Comment: if you know that $a\equiv b \pmod c$ then $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod c$

Answer (score -1):

$$2^5\equiv1(\mod31).$$
Thus, $$2^{11^{2017}}=2^{11\left(121^{1008}-1\right)+11}\equiv2^{11}\equiv2.$$
Id est we need to solve
$$7x\equiv-3(\mod31)$$ or
$$63x\equiv-27(\mod31)$$ or
$$x\equiv4(\mod31).$$