# What is the remainder of $17^{{3}^{100}}$ when divided by 60

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm stuck in this question. I tried to use the calculator to find the remainders up to $17^5$ when they got repeated, but this way seems so daunting that I think it's just not the right way to solve. Can someone provide a solution or give me a hint? Thanks.

Perhaps it might be useless, but:

$17^2=289\equiv 49 \pmod {60} \\
17^3\equiv 53 \pmod {60} \\
17^4\equiv 1 \pmod {60}\\
17^{5}\equiv 17 \pmod {60}$

Comment: Try using Euler's totient function.

Comment: $3^4\equiv1\bmod16$, so $3^{100}\equiv1\pmod{16=\phi(60)}$

Comment: Your calculationa are not useless.  $17^4 \equiv 17^0$ so $17^x$ has period $4$ mod $60$.

Comment: Closely related: [Modular Arithmetic with Multiple Exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1161176/602049)

Comment: It *is useful*: by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\bmod 60\!:\ 17^{\large\color{#0a0}4}\equiv 1\Rightarrow\ 17^{\large\color{#c00}{9^n}}\equiv 17^{\large 9^n\bmod\color{#0a0}4}\!\equiv  17^{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}\,$ by $\bmod \color{#0a0}4\!:\ \color{#c00}{9^n}\equiv 1^n\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf 1}.\,$ See the linked dupe for a systematic way to find the exponent $4$ using lcms or Carmichael's lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

$17^2=289\equiv 49 \pmod {60} \\
17^3\equiv 53 \pmod {60} \\
17^4\equiv 1 \pmod {60}\\$

$3^2=9\equiv 1 \pmod {4} \\
3^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod {4} \\$

$17^{3^{100}}\equiv 17 \pmod {60} \\$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).